# Infinite Loop trouble bash

Tags: bash

So, basically the code below is giving an infinite loop. However, if i change i+2 and f+2 to i++ and f++, they don't give an infinite loop. Can someone explain to me why this is? Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<5; i+2))
do
for ((f=0; f<5; f+2))
do
echo "$i $f"
done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `+=`, not `+` (also, i+=2 should be f+=2 in your inner loop):

```
for ((i=0; i<5; i+=2))
do
    for ((f=0; f<5; f+=2))
    do
        echo "$i $f"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`i+2` does not change the value of `i`. It simply adds 2 to the current value of `i` and returns the result. `i++` changes the value of `i` by incrementing it. Try this instead:

```
for ((i=0; i<5; i=i+2))
```

Note that `i=i+2` can also be written shorthand as `i+=2`. The meaning is the same: add 2 to the current value of `i` and assign the result to `i`.

Answer (score -1):

`+=` syntax is short form so you could also represent `i+=2` as `i=i+2`

```
for ((i=0; i<5; i+=2))
do
    for ((f=0; f<5; f+=2))
    do
        echo "$i $f"
    done
done
```

Comment: Your answer is not the same as the OP. The OP has two nested loops, you don't.

Comment: One loop is the same as two for OPs example given vars are separably defined.